# Conflict of Standard button override

Tags: lightning, button, record, new

InTesting==>
Firstly, we have users who use both Lightning and Classic.

On the account object, we have a lightning page for lightning users and vfpage for classic users. To achieve a new record creation, we used the standard new button for the classic users which have a vfpage and created a new URL button for the lightning users which was added to the list button layout.

On the account object, it's working as per requirement. but while creating an account from contact record using account lookup(New button from the dropdown),

my understanding ==> it will be using the standard button, which was supposed to be the vf page.
But, I'm getting the new lightning page here which is useful.

Production-->
Whereas, the same scenario in production is getting me the page layout but not the lighting page.

We are trying to get the same lighting page in production aswell.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.